# Error-SDK V3 cannot be smaller than SDKv4 defined in Library

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-gradle-plugin

So I am creating an app on Android Studio where I am trying to implant AdMob in my app. After done with that i am receiving the error Error-SDK V3 cannot be smaller than SDKv4 defined in Library. 
Here is my Build.Gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.o2genum.coregame"
        minSdkVersion 3
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the error `Error:(24, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 3 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:\Users\Osama\StudioProjects\CoreGame-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\7.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: What did you set the minsdk to when you started it?

Comment: Thanks Jorden yeah i really was confused about the error rather than checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using google play service library which is having a minSdk version as 9, but in your app's gradle file you have specified it as 3. So you will have to change it to 9. Make change as below,

```js
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ru.o2genum.coregame"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9
}
```

Comment: P,s can you let me know about the AdMob as in the admob guide it says go to activity_main.xml but i can't find that file anywhere.

Comment: Find the directory named layout in your project structure, you will find it there

Comment: umm i tried to find it every where in my project but i couldn't just find. P,s my app is using java files. If that matters.

Comment: I can see nothing in the Res folder except drawable and values.

Comment: Then may be you haven't created that file yet, as the name suggests it would be the xml file that defines the design of the activity, and here the class named MainActivity must be using that file. Go through the tutorial you are referencing and create these files accordingly.